# mod-mono-server4 assembly System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mono

I serached but I didn't found how to resolve this problem. I have ASP.NET application with System.Web.DataVisualization.dll. Dll is in bin folder, simple ASP.NET apps are working but when I try to run this application I got error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35' or one of its dependencies

also I have MONO_PATH=/usr/lib/mono/gac:/app_dir/bin

Comment: One more thing, I'm running it on RHEL 6.4